# Вызов неопределённого метода: app\models\forms\ShopPromoItemBuyForm::promo()?

Tags: база-данных, yii2

Добрый день получаю такую ошибку при покупки товара:

```
PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Call to undefined method app\models\forms\ShopPromoItemBuyForm::promo()

Calling unknown method: app\models\forms\ShopPromoItemBuyForm::promo()

1. in /var/www/u0598324/public_html/webstels.com/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php at line 300

                         */
    public function __call($name, $params)
    {
        $this->ensureBehaviors();
        foreach ($this->_behaviors as $object) {
            if ($object->hasMethod($name)) {
                return call_user_func_array([$object, $name], $params);
            }
        }
        throw new UnknownMethodException('Calling unknown method: ' . get_class($this) . "::$name()");
    }

    /**
     * This method is called after the object is created by cloning an existing one.
     * It removes all behaviors because they are attached to the old object.
     */
    public function __clone()
    {
        $this->_events = [];


2. in /var/www/u0598324/public_html/webstels.com/controllers/user/main/services/PromoController.php at line 47 – yii\base\Component::__call('promo', [])
41424344454647484950515253


        // if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
        //     return $this->redirect(['/promo/namesite']);

        $shop = new ShopPromoItemBuyForm();
        if ($shop->load(\Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            if ($shop->promo() === true) {
                return $this->render('success', [
                    'shop' => $shop,
                ]);
            }
        }



3. in /var/www/u0598324/public_html/webstels.com/controllers/user/main/services/PromoController.php at line 47 – app\models\forms\ShopPromoItemBuyForm::promo()
41424344454647484950515253


        // if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
        //     return $this->redirect(['/promo/namesite']);

        $shop = new ShopPromoItemBuyForm();
        if ($shop->load(\Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            if ($shop->promo() === true) {
                return $this->render('success', [
                    'shop' => $shop,
                ]);
            }
        }
```

Вот модель ShopPromoItemBuyForm.php:

```
<?php
namespace app\models\forms;

use app\helpers\BalanceHelper;
use app\helpers\RefererHelper;
use app\helpers\SettingHelper;
use app\models\ShopPromoItem;
use app\models\User;
use app\models\UserPromo;
use app\models\UserBalance;
use app\models\UserOperation;
use yii\validators\IpValidator;

class ShopPromoItemBuyForm extends UserPromo
{
public $item_id;

public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['item_id', 'required'],
        ['item_id', 'integer'],
        ['item_id', 'exist',
            'targetClass' => '\app\models\ShopItem',
            'targetAttribute' => 'id',
            'filter' => ['status' => ShopPromoItem::STATUS_ENABLED]
        ],

        ['name', 'multProtect']
    ];
}

public function scenarios()
{
    return [
        self::SCENARIO_DEFAULT => ['name']
    ];
}

public function multProtect()
{
    return;

    // disable for debug mode
    if (YII_DEBUG)
        return;

    // check evercookie
    if (isset($_COOKIE['was_promo']) && $_COOKIE['was_promo'] == "true") {
        $this->addError('name', \Yii::t('app', 'Вы уже заказывали сайт с таким названием на проекте, повторный заказ сайта с таким именем запрещён'));
    }
    $validator = new IpValidator();
    if ($validator->validate(\Yii::$app->request->userPromoIP)) {
        $ip = \Yii::$app->request->userPromoIP;
        $userPromo = UserPromo::find()->where(['id' => $ip])->limit(1)->one();
        if ($userPromo !== null) {
            $this->addError('name', \Yii::t('app', 'Вы уже заказывали сайт с таким названием на проекте, повторный заказ сайта с таким именем запрещён'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->addError('name', \Yii::t('app', 'Вы уже заказывали сайт с таким названием на проекте, повторный заказ сайта с таким именем запрещён'));
    }
}

public function buy(User $user)
{
    if (!$this->validate()) {
        \Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('warning', implode('<br />', $this->getFirstErrors()));
        return false;
    }

    if (\Yii::$app->mutex->acquire('balance_' . $user->id)) {
        \Yii::$app->db->transaction(function() use ($user) {
            $item = ShopPromoItem::get($this->item_id);
            $prices = $item->getPriceArray();

            // check balance
            foreach ($prices as $currency => $price) {
                if (!$user->balance->has($currency, BalanceHelper::convertToDigits($price))) {
                    \Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('warning', \Yii::t('app', 'Недостаточно средств на балансе'));
                    return false;
                }
            }

            // decrease balance
            foreach ($prices as $currency => $price) {
                $user->balance->decrease($currency, BalanceHelper::convertToDigits($price));
                $user->operation->create(UserOperation::OPERATION_SHOP_PROMO_BUY, $currency, BalanceHelper::convertToDigits($price), [
                    'ShopItem_id' => $this->item_id
                ]);
            }

            $item->giveTo($user);

            // give reward to referer
            RefererHelper::giveReward($user, UserBalance::CURRENCY_USD, BalanceHelper::convertToDigits($prices['usd']));

            $message = '';
            foreach ($prices as $currency => $price) {
                $message .= \Yii::t('app', '{sum} долларов', ['sum' => BalanceHelper::convertToDigits($price)]);
            }

            \Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success', \Yii::t('app', 'Вы купили «{title}»', ['title' => \Yii::t('app', $item->getTitle())]) .
                '<br />' . \Yii::t('app', 'Потрачено {price}', ['price' => $message]));

            return true;
        });
    }
}
}
```

Вот модель UserPromo.php:

```
<?php
namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\helpers\Html;

class UserPromo extends ActiveRecord
{
const STATUS_ENABLED = 'enabled';
const STATUS_DISABLED = 'disabled';
const STATUS_DELETED = 'deleted';

public static function tableName()
{
    return '{{%user_promo}}';
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['id', 'exist'],
        ['user_id', 'integer'],

        ['name', 'required'],
        ['name', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
        ['name', 'match', 'pattern' => '#^[\w_-]+$#i'],
        ['name', 'unique', 'targetClass' => self::className(), 'message' => \Yii::t('app', 'Указанное название для вашего сайта уже занято')],
        ['name', 'string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255],
    ];
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'status' => 'Статус',
        'name' => \Yii::t('app', 'Название'),
    ];
}

public static function findIdentity($id)
{
    $identity = static::findOne(['id' => $id]);
    return $identity;
}

public static function findByName($name)
{
    return static::findOne(['name' => $name]);
}

public function getName()
{
    return Html::encode($this->name);
}

public function getPromo()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Promo::className(), ['id' => 'promo_id']);
}

public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
}

public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->promo->getTitle();
}

public function getType()
{
    return $this->promo->getType();
}

public function getProfit($type)
{
    return $this->promo->{$type . '_profit'};
}
}
```

Вот моя вьюха, где пользователь и запрашивает условие в базу данных:

```
<?= FlashWidget::widget(); ?>

        <?php foreach ($items as $item) { ?>

            <?= $item->getPriceString(); ?>

                <h4 class="title">Выберите название для своего сайта</h4>
                 <?= Html::beginForm('', 'post', ['data-pjax' => true]); ?>
                 <div class="form-container">
                        <div class="form-group">
                             <?= Html::activeHiddenInput($model, 'item_id', ['value' => $item->id]) ?>
                        </div>
                        <?= Html::submitButton(\Yii::t('app', 'Купить'), ['class' => 'btn btn-upper btn-primary']) ?>
                      </div><!-- /.form-container -->
                      <?= Html::endForm(); ?>
                      <?php } ?>

                     <form role="form" class="form-inline form-cnt">
                     <div class="form-group">
                    <label>&nbsp;</label>
                    <span class="text col-md-offset-3" style="margin-left: -2%;">Проверить не занято ли данное название</span>
                   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе ShopPromoItemBuyForm.php нет метода promo(), который вызывается по коду тут:

```
if ($shop->promo() === true) {
    return $this->render('success', [
         'shop' => $shop,
    ]);
}
```

Этот метод есть у UserPromo.php. Поэтому лучше либо загружать сразу UserPromo или реализовать метод promo в ShopPromoItemBuyForm